# Upgrade 1 dimension array to 2 dimension array

Tags: php, arrays

I've got some code to work in a 1 dimension array:

```
$colour_array = [
    "1" => "#9E2A2B",
    "2" => "#3E5C76",
    "3" => "#335C67",
];

$colour1 = $colour_array[$colourdata];
...
```

I want to be able to store two colours in my array for each number, something like this I have tried quite a few things, along the lines of this:

```
$colour_array = [
    "1" => "#9E2A2B","#3E5C76",
    "2" => "#3E5C76","#3E5C76",
    "3" => "#335C67","#3E5C76",
];

$colour1 = $colour_array[$colourdata[1]];
$colour2 = $colour_array[$colourdata[2]];
```

However I don't really understand multi-dimension arrays.

Comment: Just wrap your values: `"#9E2A2B","#3E5C76"` into an array: `["#9E2A2B","#3E5C76"]`?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create arrays in array :

```
$colour_array = array(
    "1" => array("#9E2A2B","#3E5C76"),
    "2" => array("#3E5C76", "#3E5C76"),
    "3" => array("#335C67", "#3E5C76")
);
```

Or with associated arrays

```
$colour_array = array(
    "1" => array("red" => "#9E2A2B","bleu" => "#3E5C76"),
    "2" => array("green" => "#3E5C76", "orange" => "#3E5C76"),
    "3" => array("purple" => "#335C67","yellow" => "#3E5C76")
);

var_export($colour_array);
```

Output :

> ```
> array (
>   1 => 
>   array (
>     'red' => '#9E2A2B',
>     'bleu' => '#3E5C76',
>   ),
>   2 => 
>   array (
>     'green' => '#3E5C76',
>     'orange' => '#3E5C76',
>   ),
>   3 => 
>   array (
>     'purple' => '#335C67',
>     'yellow' => '#3E5C76',
>   ),
> )
> ```

If you want access some value, I would, for example, do something like this :

```
echo $colour_array[1]['blue'];
```

output :

> #3E5C76

Hope it helps !

*PS : the hex values here does not match the color names. It's just for the example.*

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. It does look good but I'm feeding into this array a number, i.e 1, 2 or 3 as my ```$colourdata``` value and I was hoping to be able to address it something like $colour_array[1][1]; to get a colour out, I don't really understand it with the names - is it possible to go back to numbers? - Ah I see it's edited now, how do I address the first one to get the value if we aren't using names?

Comment: @Jimmy Yes, see the last edit of my answer. The first solution is like you want. Access it with `$colour_array[1][1]`. For the name, it's associated array as you use it in the first level or your array. Keys values are replaced by namesinstead of integers.

Answer (score 1):

please try this one maybe this used for you

```
$colour_array = [
        "1" => "#9E2A2B",
        "2" => "#3E5C76",
        "3" => "#335C67",
    ];
    foreach ($colour_array as $key => $color) {
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($color);
        $colour_array[$key] = array();
        array_push($colour_array[$key], $color);
        array_push($colour_array[$key], "#ffffff");

    }
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($colour_array);
```